# Is a full text search on one table faster than two tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, lucene.net

In the full text search page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx on MSDN it says that if you want to do a full text search on multiple tables just "use a joined table in your FROM clause to search on a result set that is the product of two or more tables."

My question is, isn't this going to be really slow if you have to merge two very large tables?
If I'm merging a product table with a category table and there are millions of records, won't the join take a long time and then have to search after the join?

Answer (score 0):

Joins on millions of records can still be fast if the join is optimized for performance, for example, a single int column that is indexed in both tables. But there can be other factors at play so the best approach is to try it and gauge the performance yourself.

If the join doesn't perform well, you have a couple of options:

- Create a view of the tables joined together, create a full text index on that view, and run your full text queries against that view.
- Create a 3rd table which is a combination of the 2 tables you are joining, create a full text index on it, and run your full text queries against that table. You'll need something like an ETL process to keep it updated.